# Use Lumen framework to insert Chinese character

Tags: lumen

I am using Lumen framework to provide API for my main site.

A URI to insert a tag looks like this:

```
$router->get('/addtag/{id}/{tag}', 'BookController@addTag');
```

When `tag` is Chinese, it was inserted into the database encoded:

`中文` becomes `%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87`.

The database is set to `utf8m64/`.

Appreciate your input on this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue:

```
$results=DB::insert($sql, [$id, htmlspecialchars(urldecode($tag))]);
```

Looks ugly, but works so far.